What do the taxi bike numbers mean in Bangkok?
What do the taxi bike numbers mean in Bangkok? I don't know if that's only in Bangkok or across Thailand.
Example: their number is 52:


It is not hard at all to understand. This number is simply their registration number with which they are registered with the company they work for. Like in this case this folk can be easily identified in the system and all of his details can be retrieved using the number 52. You might find this in many other countries in the region.
According to the wiki, most of the drivers across the country wear orange vest. However, I have seen in some videos, drivers wearing pink one as well.

Thanks! "registered with the company they work for." what company is it? "drivers wearing pink one as well." do you recall which city?

GrabBike, Win and Gojek motorcycle taxi drivers wear orange, pink and green vests respectively.
